# Garbage collection in .Net 4.0

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, .net-4.0

Is there any change in .Net 4.0 garbage collector execution?

Answer (score 12):

Here's a blog posting:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226221026/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/sdorman/archive/2008/11/07/clr-4.0-garbage-collection-changes.aspx)

and

http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/06/Background-Collector

Answer (score 3):

There is also AppDomainResourceManager feature, which allows you to track resource usage ( Memory and CPU ) per appdomain.
the GC part of this feature is the ability to get per appdomain memory tracking.

Answer (score 3):

There's also an [ephemeron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeron) implemenation using a new class called [`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConditionalWeakTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.conditionalweaktable-2?view=net-7.0) which is [detailed here](https://web.archive.org/web/20091218101918/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/clrteam/archive/2009/05/18/the-conditional-weak-table-enabling-dynamic-object-properties.aspx).

This is useful for collecting dynamic languages which allow setting arbitary "properties" on arbitrary instances.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know of any other classes that use ephemerons?  For example, if it's desirable to create a single link from object `X` to object `Y`, is there any way to do so other than creating a `ConditionalWeakTable` instance for the purpose of holding one single link?

Comment: @supercat For that there has been [`System.WeakReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx) since .Net 1.0.

Comment: When I say a "link" from `X` to `Y`, I mean that the system will consider `Y` to have a strong rooted reference if such a reference exists to `X`, without `X` itself having to hold a reference to `Y`.  In .net 4.0, `Y` could create such a reference from `X` to itself by having a `ConditionalWeakTable myCWT` field, and performing `myCWT.Add(X, this);`.  Creating a table for the purpose of holding one item, though, seems like it would be wasteful unless the run-time cost of creating a single such item would be comparable to that of creating a table.

Answer (score 2):

Also, check out the [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/maoni/) of the developer who works on the GC, where there is an article about the new GC, plus a link to a Channel 9 interview regarding the .NET 4.0 GC.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, lots.

My latest book [Visual F# 2010 for Technical Computing](https://web.archive.org/web/20200130030623/http://www.ffconsultancy.com:80/products/fsharp_for_technical_computing/?fsb) includes a lot of performance-related information about .NET 4 as well as F# itself and the performance measurements and advice are quite different with .NET 4 and the new background garbage collector. In many cases we're seeing substantial performance improvements but there are some slowdowns as well.